# extract or unzip files in gitlab using ci/cd command line

Tags: continuous-integration, extract, unzip

Actually, I have my zip files on gitlab, I want to extract those files using gitlab CI/CD.I have tried this in .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: docker

stages:
  - build
  - test

services:
  - docker:dind

build:
  before_script:
  - apk add p7zip

  script:
  - cd \kmfs
  - 7z x -oChassisA ChassisA.zip
```

OUTPUT

```
$ apk add p7zip
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/3) Installing libgcc (6.4.0-r9)
(2/3) Installing libstdc++ (6.4.0-r9)
(3/3) Installing p7zip (16.02-r3)
Executing busybox-1.28.4-r3.trigger
OK: 11 MiB in 17 packages
$ cd \kmfs
$ 7z x -oChassisA ChassisA.zip

7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=C.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,1 CPU Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.30GHz (306F0),ASM,AES-NI)

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 3638943 bytes (3554 KiB)

Extracting archive: ChassisA.zip
--
Path = ChassisA.zip
Type = zip
Physical Size = 3638943

Everything is Ok

Folders: 1
Files: 4
Size:       24070952
Compressed: 3638943
Job succeeded
```

It is executing successfully but extracted files are not reflected in gitlab repositories and I am not able to access those files using node js code written in test stage.

So it will be great if someone suggests me any way to extract the .zip files on gitlab itself either by using commands or from nodejs code...

Comment: Did you figure this out ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use artifacts as part of your job to declared the path of the extracted zip. This will allow the subsequent jobs to access those files.

```
artifacts:
when: always
expire_in: 1 week
paths:
  - zip files folder structure after its extracted
```

Comment: What if I need to access artifacts after many days? I see it is available if the jobs are running one after another but not when they run with a gap of many days.